# Can we use 'for' and 'since' in a single sentence?

Tags: prepositions

Please see the following sentence:

> He has been on frequent furlough for last four months since  his
>   father's death.

Is this correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the sentence be "on a frequent furlough" or "on frequent furloughs"?

Comment: Also the answer is here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/175407/can-we-use-for-and-since-together-in-the-same-sentence

Comment: his father's death'; either the two temporal descriptors are in apposition (and this needs to be shown by using parenthesis, eg by using the dash), or they conflict.

Comment: Too late, but it's **the** last four months, which suggests that this was a proof reading question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule against using "for" and "since in the same sentence, for example:

> He has been looking *for* his father ever *since* he went missing.

The reason your sentence is a little jarring is that you are using "for" and "since" for exactly the same purpose - to mark the time something began. So you have a *redundancy* - saying the same thing twice.

Also, as "furlough" is a period of leave, I'm not sure "on frequent furlough" is correct. I think it should be "taking frequent furloughs" (if you mean multiple instances) or simply "on furlough".

You could simply say:

> He has been taking frequent furloughs for the last four months.

This tells you how long he has been on "frequent furlough" - four months until now.

> He has been taking frequent furloughs since his father's death.

This also tells you how long he has been on furlough - presuming you know the date of his father's death.

If you wanted to include the fact that his father died *and* that it was four months ago, a better way to express this without it sounding like a redundancy would be:

> He has been taking frequent furloughs since his father's death four months ago.